# i am using this code to move a HyperLink and a image? its moving but i want all the image and HyperLink in stright line

Tags: asp.net, html

i am using this code to move a HyperLink and a image? its moving but i want all the image and HyperLink in stright line

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" runat="server"  DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource2">
     <ItemTemplate>
           <marquee><img src="images/news-icon.jpg" width="14" height="16" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1"
                           runat="server"  Text='<%# Eval("Subject") %>' ></asp:HyperLink></marquee>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: You should really accept answers to some of your other questions before asking any more.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your images/text to appear on a single line, move your opening and closing `marquee` tags outside the `Repeater`.

Once that's done, stop using `marquee` and use one of the many [jQuery plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/marquee) that do the same thing but much better, such as [jScroller2](http://jscroller2.markusbordihn.de/example/).

While we're on the subject, it's worth mentioning that marquees and scrolling text in general are considered to be bad for usability reasons.  Aside from the fact that moving elements are distracting, links included in a marquee are difficult to click on and pose a whole host of accessibility issues for those users who have physical or visual disabilities.

You can read more about it on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marquee_element).